# keeping textarea content after a form submission

Tags: php, form-submit, forms

I am trying to keep a textbox and textarea content in its field after a form submission

text Box code:

```
<div class="response">
<span>
<input class="textbox" id="textbox1" name="textbox1" type="text"
       value="<?php if(isset($_POST['textbox1'])) {
                 echo htmlentities ($_POST['textbox1']); }?>" />
</span> </div>
```

text area code:

```
<div class="response">
<span>
<textarea  class="textarea" id="textarea1"
           name="textarea1" type="text"
           value="<?php if(isset($_POST['textarea1'])) { 
                     echo htmlentities ($_POST['textarea1']); }?>" >
</textarea>
</span>
</div>
```

textbox code is working fine, but I am not able to keep the text area content.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must add code as below,

```
<textarea  class="textarea" id="textarea1" name="textarea1" type="text">
  <?php if(isset($_POST['textarea1'])) { 
         echo htmlentities ($_POST['textarea1']); }?>
</textarea>
```

Textarea does not have value attribute.

So add `PHP` code between opening and closing `textarea` tag.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        <textarea  class="textarea" id="textarea1" name="textarea1" type="text">
        <?php if(isset($_POST['textarea1'])) {  echo htmlentities ($_POST['textarea1']); }?>
    </textarea>
```

Comment: same thing as above?